# Webview onDownloadStart never called on Android 5 or higher

Tags: android, webview, download

I have a WebView with a download listener. When I click on a link, for example: 
http://fzs.sve-mo.ba/sites/default/files/dokumenti-vijesti/sample.pdf the Android Download Manager starts. 
The problems is when I click in Android 5.0 or higher, the onDownloadStart never called. I don't know what's happening, how can i resolve it? Thank you.

```
    webView.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
        public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent,
                                    String contentDisposition, String mimetype,
                                    long contentLength) {


            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
            startActivity(i);

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has been fixed with the latest update of WebView (47.*).
Thank you!